# for/empty loop condition in python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-2.7

In Django templates, `For loop` has a `empty` conditions which gets set only when the object you are looping over is empty.
e.g:

```
{% for x in my_list %}
    #do something
{% empty %}
   <p>  my_list is empty </p>
{% endfor %}
```

here if my_list is empty then it will just print `my_list is empty`

Is there something equivalent in python?

I am using if-else conditions but that's ugly looking. I am trying to find a solution that does not involve using a if-else condition

my current code:

```
if len(my_list):
   for x in my_list:
       doSomething()
else:
    print "my_list is empty"
```

Comment: No need to use `len()`, an empty list is falsy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to stick with the `if` statement, but it can be simplified:

```
for x in my_list:
    doSomething()
if not my_list:
    print "my_list is empty"
```

since `my_list` is empty, the `for` loop never executes the loop portion, and an empty list is `False` in a boolean context.

Comment: This answers OP question but it general this won't work when iterated object is e.g. a generator. Then the options are to add flag to loop or check for `NameError: name 'x' is not defined` but the latter is more error prone. I currently have a use case where such `empty` block would solve my issue and make code more idiomatic.

Comment: @WloHu: for generators, there is no way to know, up-front, if they are going to be empty. Your options are to peek (fetch one element, if that fails, treat it as empty, if it succeeds, perhaps use `itertools.chain([peeked_element], generator)` to loop the element back in), or detect that case by setting the `for` loop target name (e.g. `x` in the loop in my answer) to a sentinel value like `None` before the loop then test if the variable is still referencing the sentinel after the loop. Only if the generator was empty and never produces the sentinel object would that condition still be true.

Comment: @WloHu: for *this question*, where the object is clearly a list (`my_list` as a variable name), there is no need to make things that complicated, however.

Answer (score 2):

if you are sure that the iterator is not returning a specific value, say `None` or `False`, then you can

```
x = False
for x in my_list:
    doSomething(x)
if x is False:
    print "my_list is empty"
```

Comment: let me stress that this will work fine even when my_list is an iterator